# How to create a tvml drop-down menu?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I want to build a TVML template that contains a Dropdown-Menu like the "All Genres" selection in the "New" tab in Apple Music.

The button is implemeted as described in Apples TVML Catalog:

```
  <separator>  
    <button>  
      <text>Options <badge class="customBadgeLayout" src="resource://button-dropdown" width="31" height="14" /></text>  
    </button>  
  </separator>
```

But how can I open a list with selectable and also clickable items by clicking on the button?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the sample TVML Catalog App?
There are good samples of templates there.
You can probably use the alertTemplate with multiple buttons, like this:

```
    <document>
       <alertTemplate>
          <background>
             <img src="/resources/images/background/bg_dark.jpg" />
          </background>
          <title>Title</title>
          <button>
             <text>Button 1</text>
          </button>
          <button>
             <text>Button 2</text>
          </button>
       </alertTemplate>
    </document>
```